# Are there any disadvantages to using EntityManager directly from a Spring @Service Bean?

Tags: java, spring

Are there any disadvantages to using an entity manager directly from a Spring Service bean rather than a @Repository bean

```
@Service
public class SomeService {
   @PersistenceContext EntityManager em; 

   @Transactional(....)
   public void doSomething(....)
   {
      // use entity manager here 
   } 
}
```

vs.

```
@Repository
public class SomeRepository {
   @PersistenceContext EntityManager em; 

   public void doSomething(....)
   {
      // use entity manager here 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the eternal debates, but it boils down to the style you wish to adhere to. In JEE6 world the question is phrased: "shoud we make separate EJBs to act as DAOs, or just use EntityManager inside our services"). I like the rule of the thumb from Adam Bien's "Real World Java EE Patterns": if you find yourself making services that just delegate to repositiories, then save yourself some complexity, cut the middle man and just use EntityManager from your service. One might argue that EntityManager IS a kind of repository.

As for possible doubts:

- EM will never throw SQLException (or any checked exception), so you probably don't need the translation @Repository gives you,
- if you ever want to reuse the functionality from somewhere else, just use the service, it is as injectable as the repository,

Style is important and people who always separate daos from services certainly have a valid point. But you can't really call a style "correct" or "incorrect", it's more in the domain of  "I like it" or "I don't like it".

Comment: BTW, `PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor` converts not only `SQLException`s but also `PersistenceException`s.

Comment: @php-coder: yes, you are right - and certainly this is a good point to mention. I was referring explicitly to checked exceptions - and unless you are using many different types of persistence in the same project, there is little difference between Spring's DataAccessException and PersistenceException.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there are:

- It separates concerns more cleanly (it hides the implementation of database access from the service class)
- If you have other services that requires similar functionality to the repository it can be reused.
- Annotating a class with `@Repository` or `@Service` clearly defines the role in the application. This is handy for if you want to use aspects.
- In Spring if you your class is annotated with `@Repository` it is eligible for  DataAccessException translation (converts `SQLException` to `DataAccessException`).